# Running async tcp connection on swiftUi chat app

Tags: asynchronous, networking, swiftui

For a school project, I have to create a swiftUi chat app.
I'm fairly new to swift but managed to use the [Network framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network) to connect to my chat server using the following code :

```
  import Foundation
    import Network
    
    class Client {
        let connection: Connection
        let host: NWEndpoint.Host
        let port: NWEndpoint.Port
        var queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "keepAlive")
    
        init(host: String, port: UInt16) {
            self.host = NWEndpoint.Host(host)
            self.port = NWEndpoint.Port(rawValue: port)!
            let nwConnection = NWConnection(host: self.host, port: self.port, using: .tcp)
            connection = BaburuConnection(nwConnection: nwConnection)
        }
    
        func start() {
            print("Client started \(host) \(port)")
            connection.didStopCallback = didStopCallback(error:)
            connection.start()
        }
    
        func stop() {
            connection.stop()
        }
    
        func sendMessage(content: String, channel: UUID) {
            let msg = Data(Frame.Message(value: content, channel: channel).serialize())
            connection.send(data: msg)
        }
        
        func sendCommand(command: CommandKind, args: [String]? = nil) {
            let cmd = Data(Frame.Cmd(cmd: Command(kind: command, args: args)).serialize())
            
            connection.send(data: cmd)
        }
        
        func isConnected() -> Bool {
            return connection.running
        }
    
        func didStopCallback(error: Error?) {
            if error == nil {
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
            } else {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
import Foundation
import Network

var KeepAlive = 30
var maxReadLength = 4096

class Connection {
    let nwConnection: NWConnection
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Client connection Q")
    var running = false
    private var serializedKA = Frame.KeepAlive().serialize()
    private lazy var timer = Timer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(KeepAlive), repeats: true) { _ in
        self.send(data: Data(Frame.KeepAlive().serialize()))
    }
    
    init(nwConnection: NWConnection) {
        self.nwConnection = nwConnection
    }
    
    var didStopCallback: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil
    
    func start() {
        print("connection will start")
        nwConnection.stateUpdateHandler = stateDidChange(to:)
        setupReceive()
        nwConnection.start(queue: queue)
        running = true
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let runLoop = RunLoop.current
            runLoop.add(self.timer, forMode: .default)
            runLoop.run()
        }
    }
    
    private func stateDidChange(to state: NWConnection.State) {
        switch state {
        case .waiting(let error):
            connectionDidFail(error: error)
        case .ready:
            print("Client connection ready")
        case .failed(let error):
            connectionDidFail(error: error)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    private func setupReceive() {
        nwConnection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: maxReadLength) { (data, _, isComplete, error) in
            if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
                let message = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("connection did receive, data: \(data as NSData) string: \(message ?? "-" )")
                switch(Frame.parse(reader: BufferedString(str: message!))) {
                case .success(let res):
                    if res is Frame.MessageWrapper {
                        print("message : ", res)
                    } else if res is Frame.Cmd {
                        print("command : ", res)
                    } else {
                        print("TODO")
                    }
                case .failure(let err):
                    print(err)
                }
            }
            if isComplete {
                self.connectionDidEnd()
            } else if let error = error {
                self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
            } else {
                self.setupReceive()
            }
        }
    }
        
    func send(data: Data) {
        nwConnection.send(content: data, completion: .contentProcessed( { error in
            if let error = error {
                self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
                return
            }
            print("connection did send, data: \(data as NSData)")
        }))
    }
    
    func stop() {
        print("connection will stop")
        self.timer.invalidate()
        running = false
        stop(error: nil)
    }
    
    private func connectionDidFail(error: Error) {
        print("connection did fail, error: \(error)")
        self.stop(error: error)
    }
    
    private func connectionDidEnd() {
        print("connection did end")
        self.stop(error: nil)
    }
    
    private func stop(error: Error?) {
        self.nwConnection.stateUpdateHandler = nil
        self.nwConnection.cancel()
        if let didStopCallback = self.didStopCallback {
            self.didStopCallback = nil
            didStopCallback(error)
        }
    }

}
```

The code works fine when I use it with a blocking operation beneath it but I can't think of any good solution for implementing it in mw swiftUi app since I need to keep some sort of reference on the Client object in order to call it's sendMessage and sendCommand methods with a button and notify my ui when I receive a message.

Does anyone has any advises ?

Also, if there is a cleaner way than recursion for async reading, I would gladly change it.